# haskell Ordering type by values and its field

Tags: haskell

I have types like

```
data Fruit = Apple Date
           | Balana Date 
           | Orange Date

f = [Apple 2020-01-01 ,Apple 2020-02-01 
     ,Balana 2020-01-01 ,Balana 2020-02-01]

getDate:: Fruit -> Date
getDate (Apple x) = x
getDate (Balana x) = x
getDate (Orange x) = x
```

when sorting the list `f` by `date` field.

```
instance Ord Fruit where
    compare f1 f2 =  compare (getDate f1) (getDate f2)
```

But ,the question is , how to setup rule to order  `Apple  2020-01-01` and `Balance  2020-01-01` ?

what if I want to sort the date first ,if the `date` are same for different types of fruits, I would order `Apple` first , then `Balance` then `Orange` ?

```
[Apple  2020-01-01, Balance  2020-01-01, Apple 2020-02-01  ,Balana 2020-02-01]
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some different approaches you can use:

The most straightfoward one is not what you want but usefull to know

```hs
data Fruit = Apple Date
           | Balana Date 
           | Orange Date
           deriving (Eq, Ord)
```

This creates automatic order for you type, but in this case it will compare the fruit first and the `Date` later... which is the opposite you want.

Therefore we need to manually define an `Ord` instance.

```hs
-- This get the date from fruit
getDate :: Fruit -> Date
getDate (Apple x) = x
getDate (Balana x) = x
getDate (Orange x) = x

-- This function compares the fruit with no date.
fruitOrder :: Fruit -> Fruit -> Ordering
fruitOrder (Apple _)  (Apple _)  = EQ
fruitOrder (Apple _)  _          = LT

fruitOrder (Orange _) (Orange _) = EQ
fruitOrder (Orange _) _          = GT

fruitOrder (Balana _)  (Balana _) = EQ
fruitOrder (Balana _)  (Apple _)  = GT
fruitOrder (Balana _)  (Orange _) = LT

-- Your ordering is a combination of both
instance Ord Fruit where
  compare f g = comparing getDate f g <> fruitOrder f g
  --            |                     |- This returns the first not EQ value or EQ if both are equal
  --            |- comparing func x y == compare (func y) (func y)
```

### A different modeling

Now, probably you are modelling your types in a non idiomatic way. If all your items will have a date, then you should encode your type as pairs as shown below

```
-- This is an alternative representation. You have Fruit types ordered as written
data FruitType = Apple | Banana | Orange deriving (Eq, Ord)

-- A fruit is a Date and a FruitType, this is Record syntax
-- you can think of it as C's structs or Python's dataclasses.
data Fruit = Fruit {getDate :: Date, getType :: FruitType} deriving (Eq, Ord)

-- The derived order is lexicographic, meaning they are ordered by the first field, and then by the second field
```

As an example, this program orders your list as expected using the suggested types

```
import Data.List

type Date = String -- For the sake of example

-- This is an alternative representation. You have Fruit types ordered as written
data FruitType = Apple | Banana | Orange deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)

-- A fruit is a Date and a FruitType, this is Record syntax
-- you can think of it as C's structs of Python's dataclasses.
data Fruit = Fruit {getDate :: Date, getType :: FruitType} deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)

f = [ Fruit "2020-01-01" Apple
    , Fruit "2020-02-01" Apple
    , Fruit "2020-01-01" Banana
    , Fruit "2020-02-01" Banana]


main = print $ sort f
```

Comment: Because of the `Semigroup (a -> b)` instance you can simplify `compare f g = comparing getDate f g <> fruitOrder f g` to `compare = comparing getDate <> fruitOrder`

Comment: @Iceland_jack wow... to much algebra for today hahaha. Nice trick